# Tagfield non-editable workaround extjs 5.0.1

Tags: extjs

Im trying to make tagfields non-editable. i.e user must not be able to type in anything and should only be able to select the values mentioned in the drop-down.
setting editable:false is just preventing me from deleting the tags using backspace but im still able to  enter data through keyboard. Is there anyway to remove the cursor from showing up after selecting entries?

```
xtype : 'tagfield',
name : 'Stage',
id:'stage',
fieldLabel: 'Stage',
labelAlign: 'top',
store: 'StageData',
selectOnFocus:false,
editable:false,
```

Comment: Can't you return the cursor on keypress or keydown events something like listeners:{keypress:function(){return;}}?

Comment: hey! I already tried doing that but it dint make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use Ext.FocusManager to avoid tagfield from getting focus, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dao

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set this property after render:

```
xtype : 'tagfield',
name : 'Stage',
id:'stage',
fieldLabel: 'Stage',
labelAlign: 'top',
store: 'StageData',
listeners:{
    afterrender:function(tf, eOpts){
        tf.setEditable(false);
    }
},
```